# Protect counter views In order not to be manipulated

Tags: php, mysql, view, counter

I have this code :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
mysql_query("UPDATE threads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
```

but when I click refresh over and over the counter increases with each refresh.

**How can I protect this counter from this with sessions or any other way?**

Comment: Do you mean you just want to count unique visits?

Comment: Yes this is what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a session variable with (hasBeenCounted) and if that is set, you do not increment.

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['hasBeenCounted'])
{
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    mysql_query("UPDATE threads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
    $_SESSION['hasBeenCounted'] = "counted";
}
```

EDIT:

```
session_start():
```

will need to be at the very top of any page that you intend to use sessions on.

Comment: +1 simple, clean. You may need to use `session_start()` before monkeying around with `$_SESSION` otherwise you'll get an error.

Comment: I understand why you may have left it out.. calling it twice will also throw an error :p

Comment: This solution is not correct because it will work on all threads for example i opened title1 then refresh this thread ok the counter will not increase , but when i i open another thread title2 for example this thead will not increase also because the session has been set from the first thead, how can to link the session to thread ID ?!

Comment: Your server has no concept of the system's thread ID. Why would it matter that multiple threads from the same system are tied together like that?

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use sessions.  However, in the end, that's not really scalable.  As a user moves through your site, you could potentially have a massive session file.  Additionally, every time a user creates a new session, you will record that view anyway.

If you only want to record a single view for a single user, you need to store that that user viewed the thread.  Depending on whether your site only allows logged in users to view threads, or if your site is open to the public, you'll have to store something unique about each user in a separate table, structured something like this (your mileage will vary on field types):

> ```
>  CREATE TABLE  `thread_views` (
> `id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY ,
> `thread_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
> `user_id` INT( 10 ) UNSIGNED NOT NULL ,
> `ts` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
> )
> ```

Every time a user views the thread, you'll need to check this table.  If there's no record in `thread_views`, insert one, and the increment the `views` column in your `threads` table.  If there is a row in `thread_views`, then you know the user has already viewed the thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think sessions with cookies are your best shot. You would probably want to set the cookie after the first visit, and then if the cookie is already set you don't update your view counter.

The syntax will be similar to this:

```
$expire=time()+2592000; //This is set to expire in 1 month (in seconds)
setcookie("visitor", "Already Visited", $expire);
```

This is how I would implement it:

```
if !(isset($_COOKIE["visitor"]))
{
   $expire=time()+2592000; //This is set to expire in 1 month (in seconds)
   setcookie("visitor", "Already Visited", $expire);
   $id = $_GET['id'];
   mysql_query("UPDATE threads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$id = $_GET['id'];

if(!isset($_SESSION['hasBeenCounted']) || $_SESSION['hasBeenCounted'] != $id)
  {
  mysql_query("UPDATE threads SET views = views + 1 WHERE id = '$id'");
  $_SESSION['hasBeenCounted'] = $id;
  }
```

I've modified the code and it works now.